# How to specify timestamps per event with measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, measurement-protocol

I'm using Measurement Protocol (for Google Analytics 4) and I'd like to send multiple events in batches to send fewer overall requests, but I'm not sure how to specify the timestamp of each individual event.

I'm sending an http post request to the measurement protocol endpoint. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=firebase#payload_post_body)
states that the post body has a `timestamp_micros` field, which is used for all events in the request, unless an event overrides it: "This value can be overridden via user_property or event timestamps".

I could not find a reference for the structure of an event item though, so I'm not sure how to override it. A key name of `timestamp` would make sense, but the post body itself uses `timestamp_micros` so maybe events follow that pattern? Or do events even use microseconds?

It's not easy to test because the raw metadata like timestamps aren't available in GA.

Comment: I don't have whole answer for you. But only small help how to see raw metadata. Within Google Analytics 4 property you can setup BigQuery export. Then you will find it in database and you can query it. Find out more here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en

Comment: Is there an answer for this @Matt C ?

I am looking to do the same, adding timestamps to event as a parameter maybe would help

Comment: @AdityaPatil yes just answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `timestamp_micros` field on each event to override the value of `timestamp_micros` on the batch request body.

Comment: How did you attach an event-specific timestamp_micros under your single payload?
For example:
A payload looks like this-
 const payload = {
      client_id: "-743850876.1630156819",
      user_properties: {
        Language: {
          value: "en-us",
        },
      },
      events: event,
timestamp_micros: xxxxxyyyyy,
    };
where the event object can be a list of different events with names and params
From  what you said, "Specify the timestamp_micros...on the batch request body." How did you add individual timestamps for all the events in the single batched payload request?